# Adjust vertical alignment of checkmark for obtained badges

Tags: bug, design, badges

This is a view of the badge description and checkmark for a specific badge (say, [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard)):

[image]

Here is the same badge description from the [list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges):

[image]

Could we adjust the vertical alignment of the checkmark in the former display to match that of the second? I suspect adjustments would have to be made for both the checkmark and the badge.

Comment: Originally posted on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254479/168244). However, the [linked duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252763/168244) seems to be considered [answered by a lengthy comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252768/168244). Since it may be site-specific, I'm drawing attention to it here again, in hopes that it could be rectified.